# Why do link tags in the head tag do not make server requests?

Tags: html, httprequest

This is just a very simple question. Why do link tags in the head tag do not make server requests?

e.g.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="_assets/_images/_favicon/favicon.ico">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="_assets/_images/_favicon/favicon.png">
```

The above two did not show any requests in the chrome dev tools network tab. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have a filter enabled. It should show up. It may be cached by the browser after getting it the first time though, so it might be loading it from cache. Clear the browser cache to see that.

Comment: Nope. Filters are off. . So link tags make server requests?

Comment: Yes, the browser must request them from the server in order to use them, but could be cached after loading it the first time.

Comment: yeah i thought that it should have made a request and just cached after loading. the network tab would note that the file came from the cache. but the link tags do not show anything. there's no entry at all in the network tab. I cleared my cache to check but its still the same. any ideas?

Comment: To make sure you're not still getting it from the cache you can in Chrome specify that you don't want caching while DEV Tools is open. Right click the "gear" on the top right corner and check off "Disable cache while Dev Tools is open"